# Genus field = Hilbert Class Field (Cox exercise 6.15)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Prove that the genus field of an imaginary quadratic field of $K$ equals its Hilbert Class Field if and only if for primitive forms of discriminant $d_k$, there is only one class per genus.

Supposedly, one should use the theorem preceding the exercise, but I don't see how. [image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the isomorphism $C(d_K) \rightarrow C(\mathcal{O}_K)\simeq Gal(H/K)$ sends the principal genus subgroup $C(d_K)^2$ to the Galois group of $H/K'$ where $K'$ is the genus field. Then $K'=H$ if and only if this subgroup is trivial, which is the same as there being only one class in the principal genus. Since all genera have the same number of classes, this is equivalent to there being one class per genus.